# Volley Response is null on devices before 4.3

Tags: android

I'm using Volley library in my Android project and trying to get an array of objects using JsonArrayRequest, I've tested it on devices before 4.3 and it doesn't work and give the error message

> "value of type string cannot be converted to jsonArray"

on the ones after 4.3. it works and gives this JSON on Toast message

> [{"cid":"9842025166","Fname":"ظ†ظˆط§ظ„","Sname":"ظ…ط­ظ…ط¯","Tname":"ظ†طµط§ط±","Faname":"ط³ظ„ط§ظ…ظ‡","fullname":"ظ†ظˆط§ظ„
>   ظ…ط­ظ…ط¯ ظ†طµط§ط±
>   ط³ظ„ط§ظ…ظ‡","gender":"ط£ظ†ط«ظ‰","nationality":"ط£ط±ط¯ظ†ظٹ","phone":"9632589632","address":"ظ†ظٹط¨طھظ†ظ†","cnumber":"","ctype":"ط¹ظ…ظٹظ„
>   ط¬ط¯ظٹط¯","ftype":"طھط·ظˆظٹط±","fnumber":"","homurl":"http://192.168.1.3/Officer/HomePictures/9842025166.png","projecturl":"","dat":"Wednesday
>   05/10/2017
>   01:57:24","Longtitude":"35.782985","Latitude":"31.714081","projLangitude":"0","projLatitude":"0","user":"111","updatinginfo":"No","kafeel":"No"}]
>   .

this is my code

```
String url = "?NAM=" + "nawal";

            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Const.Root + Const.NAME + url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                    Log.d("nn", response.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                            String fullname = jsonObject.getString("fullname");

                            String cid = jsonObject.getString("cid");

                            String Fname = jsonObject.getString("Fname");

                            String Sname = jsonObject.getString("Sname");



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
```

> this is server_side

```
<?PHP

 include_once("conn.php");

if (isset($_GET['NAM'])
    )

 {

    $NAM=$_GET['NAM'];


$query="SELECT * FROM clients where Fname='$NAM' ";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);



while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$data[]=$row;

}

echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
?>
```

Comment: are you sure you have consistent json data structure in every request?

Comment: yes it is consistent json data structure

Answer (score 0):

Finally,  this is the solution:

> encoding the URL

You don't encode the entire URL, only parts of it that come from "unreliable sources"

```
String urll = "nawal";

        String query = null;
        try {
            query = URLEncoder.encode(urll, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String url = "http://192.168.0.102/Officer/names.php?NAM=" + query;
```